# Reload Icons on Android 6.0

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, app-icons

I am running Android 6.0 with CM13. I installed a theme from the play store which changed my icons. Now even after uninstalling that theme and selecting my default android theme I don't get back my original icons. Is there a way to make android reload its icons to revert to the original icons.

Comment: What launcher are you using?

Comment: @xangua I am using Google launcher. I tried to force kill the launcher app but that didn't work as well.

Comment: Google now doesn't support theme icons, better use trebuchet or a launcher that supports themes.

Comment: Provide us a screenshot. I'm not sure which particular icons you're talking about: the ones in app drawer, the system-wide ones or something else?

Comment: @xangua The theme that I installed changed all my icons system wide for all apps even though I was using Google Launcher.

Comment: @Firelord I am referring to the system wide as well as app drawer icons. This is the link to the theme I installed

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pitchedapps.material.glass.free

Comment: Did you change your icon theme before or after installing google launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the affected app in settings and then enabling them brought back the original icon:

1. Go to *Settings › Apps*
2. Select the "All" tab
3. Scroll to the app showing up with the wrong icon on your homescreen/drawer
4. Tap its name to open the app-info
5. Tap the "Disable" button, which then changes to "Enable"
6. Tap "Enable" again

Done. Disabling the app cleared its icon from the launcher (cache?), enabling forced it to load the original one. What I did not try but maybe would solve the issue as well is clearing the cache from the launcher, then restart it (or reboot the device).

Comment: Haven't try this, and I can tell from personal experience that clearing cache and restarting won't apply the icon theme.

Comment: @xangua I was trying to restore the stock icons for Android 6.0 and not apply new icons. The theme changed the icons for Google launcher and after removing the theme some of the icons were still showing up as the themed one. Might be a bug I guess.

Comment: It's not a bug, Google now just doesn't support themes natively.